# Combine two Dataframe timestamps based on an I.D field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I am trying to figure out a way in which I can combine two dfs in pandas/python into one based on a couple of factors.

1. There is an i.d field that exists in both dfs
2. Each df has a timestamp, df_1 can have one or multiple timestamps associated with an i.d.
3. df_2 only has one timestamp associated with an I.D
4. df_2 timestamp will always be the earliest or first timestamp compared to timestamps in df_1

I want to combine both dataframes where the df_2 timestamp is the first timestamp in a column, and each subsequent timestamp from df_1 comes after.

so the output will look something like

```
I.D                  |            Timestamp
E4242                            earliest_timestamp from df_2
E4242                            next_timestamp from df_1
E4242                            next_timestamp from df_1
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always true that df2 only contains one date per ID, and that date is always the earliest date for that ID, could you simply concatenate df1 and df2, then sort by ID and timestamp? For example:

```
# Generate example data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                    'timestamp': pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01', 
                                                 '2019-01-02', 
                                                 '2019-01-15', 
                                                 '2019-01-17', 
                                                 '2019-02-01', 
                                                 '2019-02-03'])})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 
                    'timestamp': pd.to_datetime(['1959-06-01', 
                                                 '1989-12-01', 
                                                 '1999-01-25'])})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'timestamp']).reset_index(drop=True)
df

   id  timestamp
0   1 1959-06-01
1   1 2019-01-01
2   1 2019-01-02
3   2 1989-12-01
4   2 2019-01-15
5   3 1999-01-25
6   3 2019-01-17
7   3 2019-02-01
8   3 2019-02-03
```

Comment: Thanks! - what does the ignore index do? I see it ignores each records original index # but if that wasn't added as a parameter what would have happened? @Peter Leimbigler

Comment: @Chris90, `ignore_index=True` discards the default integer indexes of `df1` and `df2`, and gives the resulting `df3` a uniquely valued integer index of its own. However, if we `reset_index` after sorting, there's no need to ignore the index in `concat`; I'll edit my answer!